# mustache template with a grouped category

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm trying to render the following list:

```
    var servicesList1 = {
        services : [
            {title: "Service 1 Lorem", category: "Category 1", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 2 Lorem", category: "Category 1", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 3 Lorem", category: "Category 1", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 4 Lorem", category: "Category 1", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 5 Lorem", category: "Category 2", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 6 Lorem", category: "Category 2", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 7 Lorem", category: "Category 2", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 8 Lorem", category: "Category 2", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."}
        ]
    };
```

With the following template:

```
{{#services}}
<h3>{{category}}</h3>
<article>
    <section class="service-image {{imageClass}}"></section>
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
</article>
{{/services}}
```

But I only want {{category}} to show when the value changes.

i.e.

Category 1

```
Title 1
Description 1

Title 2
Description 2

Title 3
Description 3
```

Category 2

```
Title 4
Description 4

Title 5
Description 5

Title 6
Description 6
```

Is this doable?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: perhaps I just need to break the template into two other templates and run the logic accordingly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to restructure `servicesList1` a bit. If you want to organize the template by category you'll have to structure your data the same way.

```
var servicesList1 = {
    categories : [
        {
            name: "Category 1",
            services: [
                {title: "Service 1 Lorem", category: "Category 1", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
                {title: "Service 2 Lorem", category: "Category 1", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Category 2",
            services: [
                {title: "Service 3 Lorem", category: "Category 2", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
                {title: "Service 4 Lorem", category: "Category 2", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

And the template would be something like this.

```
{{#categories}}
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    {{#services}}
        <article>
            <section class="service-image {{imageClass}}"></section>
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
        </article>
    {{/services}}
{{/categories}}
```

You could leave the `category` property in each service object like I did, or you could take it out. I would leave it in if you use an implementation of Mustache that isn't the JavaScript one. For example the Coldfusion implementation has trouble traversing back up the chain. So, if you needed to show the category for each service I would leave it in, if not I would take it out.

Comment: @Scott You're welcome. Since Mustache has simplified logic handling sometimes you just have to put some extra work into your data structures.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done if you change the object to something like:

```
var servicesList1 = {
    categories:[
        {name: "Category 1", services:[
            {title: "Service 1 Lorem", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 2 Lorem", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 3 Lorem", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 4 Lorem", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
        ]},
        {name: "Category 2", services:[
            {title: "Service 5 Lorem", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 6 Lorem", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 7 Lorem", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."},
            {title: "Service 8 Lorem", imageClass : "", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit aliquam interdum."}
        ]}
    ]
};
```

and your template could look like:

```
{{#categories}}
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    {{#services}}
        <article>
            <section class="service-image {{imageClass}}"></section>
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
        </article>
    {{/services}}
{{/categories}}
```

this should get the job done; but if you cannot change the object I suggest to run a javascript function.